# Adding subview outside UICollectionViewCell contentView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I'm having a very specific problem here.

In the past I've tried adding UIButton to a UITableViewCell.

The problem is, it's not 100% reliable. Sometimes the cell will get selected instead of the UIButton.

I've found that it's impossible to remedy this problem using UITableView, so instead I've switched to UICollectionView, thinking maybe it will offer more flexibility.

I'm not really sure what to do at this point.

I need one top part of the cell to be selectable.

The bottom part should have 2 UIButtons, each performing a different selector.

I still cannot figure out a way to add these buttons outside of the contentView.

If I add these buttons inside the contentView and make the cell not selectable by passing back nil in a delegate method, the buttons become entirely unusable.

Answer (score 1):

You **must** use  *contentView* for your own subviews in cells (both table and collection).
Behaviour in other cases is undefined.